I am having trouble figuring out how add to a global list using functions in python3
So, I can't figure out how to get this loop to iterate, or why it isn't adding to the global list the values that are entered. I've included my code so far below. Any help is greatly appreciated.
get_values() – This function takes no arguments. It should prompt
for, and get, numbers from the user and store them in a list. One
the program has all the values (either the user typed "QUIT" or they
inputted 10 values) this function should return the list to the
calling code.
values = []
max_num = 10
####function to prompt users for input
##and return that input
def get_values():
    while len(values) < max_num or value != 'quit':
        value = float(input('Enter a number or type quit to quit: '))
        values.append(value)
        return values 
    
##find the average of the list   
def avg(list):
    return sum(values) / len(values)

##define the main function             
def main():
    get_values()
    avg(values)
    average = avg([values])
    print()
    print(f'The average is: {average:,.1f}')

As it runs now it takes one prompt and then completes the whole program without asking for more input.
I don't know what to try next. This is really stumping me and has been for the last 6 hours.

This should fail with a NameError at or value != 'quit'…!?

You're returning values inside the loop. That ends the loop and function. It's also pointless to return the list since you're intent on using a global variable instead.

You're never using the list parameter in avg, so it's pointless to require it and pass it. You also shouldn't name a variable list, as that shadows the builtin list function.

There are probably too many errors here for this to be useful for future visitors. Each of them individually is very common; please search before asking.

sorry @tripleee , I am very new to python and programming in general.

First of all you need to change the way you check if user enters quit.
Because you're making all inputs float and you'll get ValueError.
Then, you only need to define Values and max_num as global so that you'll have access to them in your function's namespace too.
Also, you had a mistake in def get_values() return statement's indentation; That's why your script only gets 1 input and ends the loop. Actually, you don't even need to return anything, because the values list is in global scope and other function has access to it too.
So your code will start like this:
global values, max_num
values = []
max_num = 10

####function to prompt users for input
##and return that input
def get_values():

while len(values) < max_num:
    value = input('Enter a number or type quit to quit: ')
    if value != 'quit':
        value = float(value)
        values.append(value)


The global statement here doesn't do anything. Even if you put it into the function where it belongs, it'd still be superfluous.
